# It's really strange that sometimes gcc can't find reference of sqrt but sometimes gcc can

Tags: c, gcc, ld, math.sqrt

I tried this code

```
/*main.c*/
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* sqrt */

int frequency_of_primes (int n) {
  int i, j;
  int freq = n - 1;
  for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
  for (j = sqrt(i); j > 1; --j)
    if (i%j==0) {--freq; break;}
  return freq;
}

int main() {
  printf("%f\n", sqrt(4.0));
  return 0;
}
```

and compiled it with `gcc main.c`, it reported that `undefined reference to`sqrt'`. I already know add`-lm` option can resolve this issue. But what really surprises me is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* sqrt */

// int frequency_of_primes (int n) {
//   int i, j;
//   int freq = n - 1;
//   for (i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
//   for (j = sqrt(i); j > 1; --j)
//     if (i%j==0) {--freq; break;}
//   return freq;
// }

int main() {
  printf("%f\n", sqrt(4.0));
  return 0;
}
```

The `main` function also calls `sqrt`, but `ld` doesn't report any errors.

Comment: If you add `-ffast-math`, most compilers will use the appropriate machine instructions instead of a function call, so you don't need libm.... Even for non-constants.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because the optimizer is handling the constant case you're using.

It's the `sqrt(i)` call inside `frequency_of_primes()` that's the problem, the call in `main()` is optimized out. You can figure that out by reading the generated code for the latter case, it'll just load a constant `2.0` and be done with it.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your answer. Replace sqrt(4.0) with sqrt(i) which double i = 4.0 and compile with gcc -O3 then no error reported, but not when compile without optimizing.